# Django Admin Customizing

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-templates, customization

I am designing an admin interface where invite mails will be sent to users. My Invitation model is ready & in my invitation admin interface I am able to see my added users for which the admin can send email invites. [image: admin interface so far]

now I want to customize this a bit. I want to add for each row a `SEND` button which will actually send an email to that user. Sending email function etc. are all ready. I am not getting as to how I can customize this admin template to add a `send` button. Can someone help ?? or atleast point me in the right direction...

**P.S:** it need not be a send button, it could be part of "action" dropdown where for the selected users I can jointly send emails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the send button for each row, you can give your model (or ModelAdmin) a new function which returns the corresponding HTML pointing to your views (or calling corresponding AJAX functions). Just add your function to the ModelAdmin's "list_display" and make sure that HTML tags don't get escaped:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = ('name', 'email', 'sender', 'send_email_html')

    def send_email_html(self, obj):
        # example using a javascript function send_email()
        return '<a href="send_email(%s)">Send Now</a>' % obj.id
    send_email_html.short_description = 'Send Email'
    send_email_html.allow_tags = True
```

Regarding the use of an action, define "actions" in your ModelAdmin as a list containing your function which takes modeladmin, request, queryset as parameters:

```
def send_email_action(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    whatever_you_want_to_do_with_request_and_queryset
send_email.short_description = 'Send email'

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    actions = [
        send_email_action
    ]
```

Comment: cool! this is pretty good. when the admin clicks "send" how would I go about adding functionality to this? basically upon clicking send the entire row has to be sent to my `send_email_view` which sends the email...

Comment: sorry, just re-read your answer. So you suggest the ajax route which from javascript sends the entire row to my `send_email_view`. Are there any other ways ?

Comment: Sorry didn't check SO for a while... Hmmm... you could add a submit button to each row - putting the corresponding row's object id in its name - and then check which button was clicked instead of looking which checkboxes were ticked. So basically like the action but reading a single object from the button name instead of the checkboxes.

Answer (score 4):

My solution below is for adding the "send invite" action in admin interface

**"Send Invite" action**

You can refer to the django admin-actions documentation [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/).
Here is what your admin.py should look like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import MyModel
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['send_invite']

    def send_invite(self, request, queryset):
        # the below can be modified according to your application.
        # queryset will hold the instances of your model
        for profile in queryset:
            send_email(subject="Invite", message="Hello", from_eamil='myemail@mydomain.com', recipient_list=[profile.email]) # use your email function here
   send_invite.short_description = "Send invitation"

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

I have not tested this code, but it is pretty much what you need. Hope this helps.