# Django admin app to send mail to users

Tags: django, email, django-admin

Is there a Django app or extension that can be used from the admin panel to select users and send mails to them?

Possibly with a markup editor?

Comment: Does it have to be from the literal admin? Why not an app which is only available to users where `User.is_staff == True`?

Answer (score 1):

After a quick google search the only app I found that could fit is [django-mailer](https://github.com/jtauber/django-mailer/).

#### Sample Use Cases

- a site admin wants to send a one-off announcement to all users on a site
- a site admin wants to send a one-off email to a subset of users (e.g. thank you note to users who completed a survey)
- a site admin wants to send an email but wants to defer it to a particular date or time (e.g. send out at 9am tomorrow a reminder of the scheduled downtime at 10am)
- a site admin wants to send a regular email to a subset of users (e.g. people who haven’t logged in for over a month)

Another way would be to customize yourself the admin. I invite you to read this thread:
[Django Admin Customizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803547/django-admin-customizing)